# Webscraping in Python - I am getting special characters in price column but there is no special character in the webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Webpage I am scraping from is books.toscrape.com
My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
URL = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-'

books=[]
Price=[]
Stock_availability=[]
Books_url=[]
# For loop to crawl and get information from multiple pages.
for page in range(1,6):
    Source = requests.get(URL + str(page) + '.html')
    Scrape = BeautifulSoup(Source.text,'html.parser')
    #print(Scrape.prettify()) 

    # Grabbing book titles
    for article in Scrape.find_all('article'):
        books.append(article.h3.a.text)
        #print(books)
    #Grabbing book price
        Price.append(article.find('div', class_ = 'product_price').p.text)
        #print(Price)
    #Grabbing stock availability of each book
        Stock = Scrape.find('p', class_ = 'instock availability').text.strip()
        Stock_availability.append(Stock)
        #print(Stock_availability)
        
    #Grabbing the link of each book
        for link in article.find_all('a',href = True):
            url = link['href']
        Books_url.append('https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/' + url)
        #print(Books_url)   
         
Scraped_Data = {'TITLE':books,'PRICE':Price,'STOCK AVAILABILTY':Stock_availability,'URL':Books_url}
Scraped_Books = pd.DataFrame(Scraped_Data)
Scraped_Books[:5]
Scraped_Books.to_csv('SCB.csv',index = None)
```

#---------
#my output shows the special character  "Â" before the price

```
#0     Â£51.77
#1     Â£53.74
#2     Â£50.10
#3     Â£47.82
#4     Â£54.23
```

my CSV file export shows the same special character again followed by a comma
Â, Â£51.77  -- but there is no special character in the webpage except the currency symbol.

What is wrong with my code, please?  Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's an encoding issue.  Try `Scrape = BeautifulSoup(Source.content,'html.parser')`

Comment: This is almost certainly UTF-8 being interpreted as Windows code page 1252. Probably look for duplicates around that; this is a very common FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

This is an encoding issue. This should fix it:

```
Price.append(article.find('div', class_ = 'product_price').p.text.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
```